# React Router Dom upgrade error - Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

After installing the latest version v6 getting this error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

The code works well for lower versions but fails for version6.

Code:
index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,

  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
let App = () => {
  return (
    <>
    
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';

let Home = () => {
  return <h1>Home</h1>;
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 3):

In V6, React Router added some breaking changes & one of them is they replaced **Switch** with **Routes**. Also, instead of `component={Home}` it should be `element={<Home/>}`

Answer (score 2):

In v6, Switch is no longer supported use Routes instead. Use Element as attribute instead of component.

```
 <Routes>
 <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
 </Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `react-router-dom` after `Version-6` no longer available **Switch**, instead of Switch we should use **Routes**

**Error:** react-router-dom: Version 6 before

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      users: [],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello User!</h1>


        <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/home" component={<Home />}/>
              <Route exact path="/login" component={<Login />}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Solution:** react-router-dom: Version 6 after we should use Routes, `component` instead of `element` property in Route to assign dom.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      users: [],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello User!</h1>


        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```